# Angular : Add a "free input option" in a <mat-select>

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have this code :

```
'<mat-form-field>
      <mat-select #Version >
        <mat-option value="1.36.0">1.36.0</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="1.42.0">1.42.0</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="1.43.5">1.43.5</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="1.44.2">1.44.2</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>'
```

Problem is, the user might need to add a new version every now and then. So I'd like to add an option where the user can fill with his keyboard a new version that is not listed in this field yet. Do you guys have any idea how to achieve that ?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xxselg

https://angular-xxselg.stackblitz.io

Comment: @Zoko Please share your code on https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I have and searched for answers and couldn't find anything. I wanted to add a text input as a mat-option, but couldn't make it work in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all,you need to create new string array. and use *ngFor.

You can use [mat-input](https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples) in order to get the new version.And, [mat-button](https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview) in order to update the array.

Take a look at this [Stackblitz exmaple](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ayurb4?file=src/app/app.component.html) that shows how to implement that.

By the way,Your Stackblitz Example were missing the angular material styling.
Added : `"~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";`
under styles.css.

More about angular material styling [Here](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming).

Comment: Yeah still learning, sorry about that. I can make your solution work. It's sad that the mat-select component doesn't allow this. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Amit Baranes that a nice answer. But we can add a duplicate version in that.

Answer (score 2):

Was looking for a similar solution and as far as I can tell, mat-select doesn't help do what you want here without adding a separate input field as detailed above, but imho, that's a bad solution from a user experience perspective.

If you simply use mat-autocomplete instead of mat-select it provides the basic functionality (select or free data entry) in a single control e.g. look at the 'Simply Autocomplete' [example here](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples)